# Parsing List of image From Json data to Piccaso image loader

Tags: android, json, picasso

i have this [Json Data](https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json)

and i prasing the data in in this json to this ,,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlQon.jpg)

now i wont when click on the image of the application ,, open another activty and display the images in the "im:image" Jsonarray in the json ! 
this code give to me all images ,, but i wont just the image thats i clicked

this is my Module

```
 private List<String> Allimage = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> getAllimage() {
    return Allimage;}
public void setAllimage(List<String> allimage) {
    Allimage = allimage;}
```

the Adapter

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<AppShowModule> appShowModules;
List<AppShowModule> imageUrls ;

Context context;
public ImageListAdapter(List<AppShowModule> appShowModules, Context context){
    super();
    this.appShowModules = appShowModules;
    this.context = context;}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.imagelayout, parent,false );
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder( v );
    return viewHolder;}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final AppShowModule appShowModule = appShowModules.get( position );
    Picasso.with(context).load( appShowModule.getAllimage() ).into( holder.appImage );

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return appShowModules.size();
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView appImage;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        appImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.appImage);
    }}}
```

and this is the Fragment `

```
public class ImageListFragment extends Fragment {

List<AppShowModule> appShowModules;
Context context;
List<AppShowModule> imagesModule;
RecyclerView AppRecyclerView;
ImageView Imageview;
RecyclerView.Adapter imageRecyclerViewadapter;
List<String> imageUrls;
String feedKey = "feed";
String entryKey = "entry";
String nameKey = "im:name";
String imageKey = "im:image";
String labelKey = "label";
String artistKey = "im:artist";
String contentTypeKey = "im:contentType";
String attribueKey = "attributes";
String rightsKey = "rights";
String categoryKey = "category";
String relaseDateKey = "im:releaseDate";
String linkKey = "link";
String hrefKey = "href";
String summaryKey = "summary";
String jsonUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json";
RequestQueue requestQueue;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public ImageListFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_list, container, false);
}
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    AppRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageRecyclerView);
    imagesModule = new ArrayList<>();
    appShowModules = new ArrayList<>();
    imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonAppShowData();
}
public void JsonAppShowData() {
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray( "entry" );
                AppShowModule appShowModule = new AppShowModule();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    String image = response.getJSONObject(feedKey).getJSONArray(entryKey).getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray(imageKey).getJSONObject( 0 ).getString(labelKey).toString();
                    imageUrls.add(image);
                    appShowModule.setAllimage(imageUrls);
                    appShowModules.add(appShowModule);
                }
                imageRecyclerViewadapter = new ImageListAdapter(appShowModules,getContext());
                AppRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageRecyclerViewadapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e( "LOG", error.toString() );
        }
    } );
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( getContext() );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager( getContext().getApplicationContext(),3);
    AppRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);    }}
```

Comment: If you check the Picasso documentation, it clearly only loads one string. I'm not sure why you thought you could load a List

Comment: totally agree with @cricket_007 plus your onResponse() code totally messy. I am afraid your concept is not clear.

Comment: thank you for answer i find the solution for piccaso but still have a problem i json this code give to me all urls i wont just the array urls !

Comment: this is a json data for applications ,, and i parsing it ! but i have a problem here ! for example if i click on "whatsapp" i wont to display image for whats app that contain in the array ,, but this code give me all of image for all application

Comment: I think you want to make a **new** AppShowModule each time through the loop. Set the one image data on it, and add that to AppShowModules list. Currently, you're only adding one instance of the object, so you'll have N copies of it

Comment: Also, you've already accepted the answer, so the recommended action here on StackOverflow is to create a new post for new questions once the site lets you. In the mean time, try to debug the problems yourself and take the time to think about what could be wrong with your approach

Comment: i edit my question plz see it

Comment: this is the qustion with all details plz if you have any idea try to answer 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429158/parsing-jsonarray-to-picasso-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load complete `list` string by doing `appShowModule.getAllimage()` which is wrong. try to do following.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(appShowModule.getAllimage().get(position)).into(holder.appImage);
```

Comment: thank you its working :) but its give to me all the urls in the json i wont just the urls that i click to it !!

Comment: hhhhh it tried to accept but i got this ,, accept
×
You can accept an answer in 4 minutes

Comment: this is a json data for applications ,, and i parsing it ! but i have a problem here ! for example if i click on "whatsapp" i wont to display image for whats app that contain in the array ,, but this code give me all of image for all application

Comment: @MoayedI.Alayseh _but its give to me all the urls in the json i wont just the urls that i click to it_  I couldn't understand this. would you please explain? Happy to help you :)

Comment: i try to explain what the problem in the coments :) thank you for help me

Comment: share your json and exact requirement

Comment: this is the qustion with all details plz if you have any idea try to answer 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429158/parsing-jsonarray-to-picasso-library)