# parsing JsonArray to Picasso library

Tags: android, json

i have this [Json Data](https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json)

and i prasing the data in in this json to this ,,

[image]

now i want when user click on the image of the application open another activty which have a recyceler view and display the images in the "im:image" json array in the json ! this code give to me all images ,but i wont just the image thats i clicked any idea ??

this is my Module

```
public class AppShowModule{

 private List<String> Allimage = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> getAllimage() {
    return Allimage;}
public void setAllimage(List<String> allimage) {
    Allimage = allimage;}
```

the recycler view adapter

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<AppShowModule> appShowModules;
List<AppShowModule> imageUrls ;

Context context;
public ImageListAdapter(List<AppShowModule> appShowModules, Context context){
    super();
    this.appShowModules = appShowModules;
    this.context = context;}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.imagelayout, parent,false );
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder( v );
    return viewHolder;}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final AppShowModule appShowModule = appShowModules.get( position );
    Picasso.with(context).load(appShowModule.getAllimage().get(position)).into(holder.appImage);

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return appShowModules.size();
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView appImage;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        appImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.appImage);
    }}}
```

and this is the fragment

```
public class ImageListFragment extends Fragment {

List<AppShowModule> appShowModules;
Context context;
List<AppShowModule> imagesModule;
RecyclerView AppRecyclerView;
ImageView Imageview;
RecyclerView.Adapter imageRecyclerViewadapter;
List<String> imageUrls;
String feedKey = "feed";
String entryKey = "entry";
String nameKey = "im:name";
String imageKey = "im:image";
String labelKey = "label";
String artistKey = "im:artist";
String contentTypeKey = "im:contentType";
String attribueKey = "attributes";
String rightsKey = "rights";
String categoryKey = "category";
String relaseDateKey = "im:releaseDate";
String linkKey = "link";
String hrefKey = "href";
String summaryKey = "summary";
String jsonUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json";
RequestQueue requestQueue;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public ImageListFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_list, container, false);
}
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    AppRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageRecyclerView);
    imagesModule = new ArrayList<>();
    appShowModules = new ArrayList<>();
    imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonAppShowData();
}
public void JsonAppShowData() {
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray( "entry" );
                AppShowModule appShowModule = new AppShowModule();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    String image = response.getJSONObject(feedKey).getJSONArray(entryKey).getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(imageKey).getJSONObject(0).getString(labelKey).toString();
                    imageUrls.add(image);
                    appShowModule.setAllimage(imageUrls);
                    appShowModules.add(appShowModule);
                }
                imageRecyclerViewadapter = new ImageListAdapter(appShowModules,getContext());
                AppRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageRecyclerViewadapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e( "LOG", error.toString() );
        }
    } );
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( getContext() );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager( getContext().getApplicationContext(),3);
    AppRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);    }}
```

Comment: Give me some time. I will answer you

Comment: ok iam waiting you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are fetching first image from each array by doing following

> ....getJSONArray(entryKey).getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(imageKey).getJSONObject(0)...

whereas you need to fetch all the images related to selected image from the array so iterate your array on the inner image array `im:image`, not on outer main array `entry`. follow these steps

1. Whenever you click on the image item then get the id of that item.
2. iterate on the outer array `entry` and check if the clicked items id matches in the array `entry`.
3. when it matches id then iterate on inner array `im:immage` and store those images in your list. And apply that list to your `recyclerview`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for answer me , but how i can chek if the clicked item is matches?

Comment: you need to set id of clicked item as tag to your `imageview` as `imageview.setTag("imageview id");` and then When that imageview is clicked then you can get that id in `onClick()` as `String id = (String) v.getTag();`

Comment: you mean i have to add this on to the Previous activity ! because here i dont have a onclick !

Comment: @moayed ayasaa Yes exactly you need to add it in previous activity and the send id via intent to next activity and do the further operations

Comment: ok i understand but the id that i taken from intent ? where i will use it ?!

Comment: @moayedayasaa you have to use  it while you are iterating from jsonarray for matching your clicked image item

Comment: id to lisk this  `String image = imageArray.getJSONObject(j).getString(labelKey).toString();
                            if (image == id)
                            {
                            imageUrls.add(image);
                            appShowModule.setAllimage(imageUrls);`
but its not working :\

Comment: It's very simple. Just follow the steps in my answer and comments. It's very hard to tell as i don't have all of your resources

Comment: i know that and I'm sorry to bother you but i dont understand, can you just tell me what will where use the id ? :\

Comment: @moayedayasaa I don't know why again you unaccepted my answer. This is really demotivating me. Please don't do that as moderators are always moderating our behaviour and they may block your account as you are playing with stackoverflow.

Comment: please check this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436616/error-in-parsing-json-array-to-picasso)